# in angular2 How can load multiple component in one page

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have created simple page at angular 2 
I am trying to add same component (example: "my-app") at the same page multiple times, the first one is loaded correctly but the remaining  they didn't (at example below : showing "Loading..." ) ,

here is some code : -index.html-

```
 <body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  </body>
```

--app.ts--:

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

the full demo here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/18afY0M19JHML6Ve1huc

please help

Answer (score 0):

If I may ask, why are you trying to load multiple versions of the same component?
If it's for an array of objects, it's better to load the entire array in a single component, then use an *ngFor loop to display each one individually.
so rather then having multiple `<my-app>` elements, instead have a single `<apps-container>` element (or any name really, within which you can have something like:

`<my-app *ngFor="#app of apps">
</my-app>`

Then for any function within the component that changes that component, send the selected component to the function so it edits that one in particular.
An example of this is in the angulario docs
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html

I've edited your example to show you what I mean
http://plnkr.co/edit/GzmiViYLWqMWZfta6Mck

UPDATE: Ok, here's an updated example using iFrames that basically gets the job done. Basically the component is loaded as an iFrame, so each one is separate from the next.
http://plnkr.co/edit/xWKGS6

Comment: HI @MSwehli, this is just a sample component , to ask on how to add different instance of the component into one page and may pass it later different inputs , I can say like adding in the page the same  weather widget in different places , so my question how can I add   many instances of the same component into the page .

Comment: Oh ok, as far as i know there isn't a way yet, however what i would do is host the app seperately on a page other then index, then use iframe everywhere i need it though haven't tried that yet to be honest, but worth a shot. Atleast until they allow you to override the selector when bootstrapping.

Comment: I've edited my answer above to a new plnkr link that shows multiple components int he same page using iframes.